# Maven: Full reactor summary after resume a build with mvn goal -rf :module

Tags: maven

I'm using maven to manage the build of a large project that it's divided in several modules that are built from the root. So, in this case, maven will use the reactor functionality to build each module in the correct order.Something like this:

```
root/pom.xml
    sp1/pom.xml
    sp2/pom.xml
    sp3/pom.xml
    sp4/pom.xml
```

I build the project with maven from root directory using the command

```
mvn clean install
```

If the build is OK, maven will print the reactor summary:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Root Project ....................................... SUCCESS [ 18.271 s]
[INFO] sp1 ................................................ SUCCESS [  2.034 s]
[INFO] sp2 ................................................ SUCCESS [ 22.770 s]
[INFO] sp3 ................................................ SUCCESS [03:39 min]
[INFO] sp4 ................................................ SUCCESS [04:39 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-04T17:08:11+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 256M/1599M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But, What happens if one of build phase of one of the subproject fails?. For example, some tests in the sp2 subproject fail and I fix them and relaunch the build from the sp2 with this command

```
mvn clean install -rf :sp2
```

The project is built correctly. Then, maven prints the reactor, but not the full reactor, only from sp2. Something like this:
```

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] sp2 ................................................ SUCCESS [ 22.770 s]
[INFO] sp3 ................................................ SUCCESS [03:39 min]
[INFO] sp4 ................................................ SUCCESS [04:39 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-04T17:08:11+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 256M/1599M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is: Is it possible to obtain the full reactor summary (including the modules that have been built in the previous execution?)

Answer (score 0):

*Reactor Build Order* is resolved during *[Reactor Sorting](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)* which leads into a deterministic sequence of execution  for the list of projects. The command `--resume-from` (-rf) as used in:

```
mvn clean install -rf :sp2
```

resumes reactor build from the specified project, where the order is similar to as was already been decided, it simply traverses the remaining of the projects in the list which is the updated Reactor Build Order and hence the *Reactor Summary* corresponds to the new build order.